# Ubuntu 20.04 on a Windows tablet

Tags: dual-boot, tablet

I have a Kruger&Matz Edge 1162 tablet with Windows 10 preinstalled and I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 on it. I already tried it once but it didn't seem to take. The installation finished, no problems, but when I restarted the tablet it just took me straight to the Windows log-in screen.

My question is, if I choose to install Ubuntu and wipe Windows completely, would that break anything?

Answer (score 1):

It should't break anything. Make sure you check the specs on the tablet work on Linux//Ubuntu. If something does not, you might get an error while booting or something will not work.